# We have come too far or we have came too far?

Tags: american-english, tenses

Which is correct? "It has to be end here. We have come too far" is it correct? Or it should be came?

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence in the quote should be, "It has to end here," or "It has to be ended here."

As for the second sentence, it's present progressive tense in first person plural, which is formed by "have" + past participle.  The past participle of the verb, "come," is "come," so it should be, "We have come too far."